# Avoiding duplicate user entries in array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I'm working on an assignment and I need to throw an exception if the user entry already exists in the array but I can't get it to work. I have to use an array and it can't be an arrayList. If the entry doesn't exist in the array it should be added.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    try {
                boolean duplicates = false;
                num = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());

                for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                    if (num == (array[i])) {
                        duplicates = true;
                    }
                }
                array[index] = num;
                index++;
                if(!duplicates){
                    throw new DuplicateValueException();}


            } // end try
```

Thanks!

Comment: is your list sorted ?

Comment: Your code throws a fit if there are **no** duplicates, not if there **are** duplicates. Change `if (!duplicates)` to `if (duplicates)`. Also, move `array[index] = num; index++;` after the exception is thrown, or you will add an element anyway, exception or no.

Comment: FWIW - you might as well get rid of the `duplicates` variable entirely and just throw `DuplicateValueException` where you currently set it to `true`. Less code, and easier to read.

Comment: Do you need to use an array?

Comment: @Colin Morelli This worked like a charm. Fixing the (!duplicates) also works but as you said it is more code! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic appears to be reversed.

```
if(!duplicates){
```

should be

```
if(duplicates){
```

And, you should really check before you add the value

```
if (duplicates){
  throw new DuplicateValueException();
}
array[index] = num;
index++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, more compact:

```
try {
    num = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());
    int i=0;
    while((i < index) && (num != array[i])) {
        i++;
    };
    if (i<index){ //if i<index is because it found an element in the array
        throw new DuplicateValueException();
    }
    else   { //if i=index is because a duplicate element in the array was not found
        array[index++] = num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
try {
                boolean duplicates = false;
                num = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());

                for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                    if (num == (array[i])) {
                        duplicates = true;
                    }
                }
                if(duplicates){
                    throw new DuplicateValueException();}
                array[index] = num;
                index++;

            } // end try
```